# How to set focus programmatic on gridview item?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

My home page has a `ListView`, which contains many `GridView`(one row enabled).
Now I can set focus using keyboard `left/right/up/down`. But when enter an item(I use a global variable to store this item), navigate to another page, and navigate back, I can't set the previous `GridView` item's focus.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        //Set last focus, if no focus, banner get the focus.              
        if (Globals.gridViewItemFocused == null)
            banner.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
        else
        {
            list.UpdateLayout();

            Globals.gridViewItemFocused.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
            Globals.gridViewItemFocused.IsSelected = true;
            Globals.gridViewItemFocused.StartBringIntoView();
        }
    }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Setting focus on a variable of GridViewItem type will not work. You need to set your GridView control's SelectedItem or SelectedIndex according to your variable.

Comment: Thanks, got it. @Xavier Xie - MSFT can you move this comment to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting focus on a variable of GridViewItem type will not work. You need to set your GridView control's SelectedItem or SelectedIndex according to your variable.